# how to catch custom exception in try-except method in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I want test something that raise custom exception using pytest.

test target method

```py
def string_to_datetime(input_string):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(input_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    except Exception:
        raise DateTimeFormatException(input_string, 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss')
```

my test code

```py
def test_string_to_datetime():
    with pytest.raises(DateTimeFormatException) as e:
        string_to_datetime('sometext')
    assert e.value.parameter == 'sometext'
    assert e.message == 'sometext format is YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss only'
```

my custom exception

```py
class DateTimeFormatException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, parameter, datetime_format):
        super(DateTimeFormatException, self).__init__()
        self.parameter = parameter
        self.datetime_format = datetime_format
        self.message = f'{parameter} format is {datetime_format} only'
        self.response = MyResponse(self.status_code) \
            .code(Fail.INVALID_FORMAT) \
            .message(self.message) \
            .add_field('invalid parameter', self.parameter).build()
```

test failed, and fail log

```
test_datetime_util.py F
test\util\test_datetime_util.py:6 (test_string_to_datetime)
input_string = 'sometext'

    def string_to_datetime(input_string):
        try:
>           return datetime.datetime.strptime(input_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

..\..\app\util\datetime_util.py:8: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

cls = <class 'datetime.datetime'>, data_string = 'sometext'
format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

    def _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"):
        """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
        format string."""
>       tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)

C:\Users\RIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\_strptime.py:565: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

data_string = 'sometext', format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

    def _strptime(data_string, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"):
        """Return a 2-tuple consisting of a time struct and an int containing
        the number of microseconds based on the input string and the
        format string."""

        for index, arg in enumerate([data_string, format]):
            if not isinstance(arg, str):
                msg = "strptime() argument {} must be str, not {}"
                raise TypeError(msg.format(index, type(arg)))

        global _TimeRE_cache, _regex_cache
        with _cache_lock:
            locale_time = _TimeRE_cache.locale_time
            if (_getlang() != locale_time.lang or
                time.tzname != locale_time.tzname or
                time.daylight != locale_time.daylight):
                _TimeRE_cache = TimeRE()
                _regex_cache.clear()
                locale_time = _TimeRE_cache.locale_time
            if len(_regex_cache) > _CACHE_MAX_SIZE:
                _regex_cache.clear()
            format_regex = _regex_cache.get(format)
            if not format_regex:
                try:
                    format_regex = _TimeRE_cache.compile(format)
                # KeyError raised when a bad format is found; can be specified as
                # \\, in which case it was a stray % but with a space after it
                except KeyError as err:
                    bad_directive = err.args[0]
                    if bad_directive == "\\":
                        bad_directive = "%"
                    del err
                    raise ValueError("'%s' is a bad directive in format '%s'" %
                                        (bad_directive, format)) from None
                # IndexError only occurs when the format string is "%"
                except IndexError:
                    raise ValueError("stray %% in format '%s'" % format) from None
                _regex_cache[format] = format_regex
        found = format_regex.match(data_string)
        if not found:
            raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
>                            (data_string, format))
E           ValueError: time data 'sometext' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

C:\Users\RIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\_strptime.py:362: ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    def test_string_to_datetime():
        with pytest.raises(DateTimeFormatException) as e:
>           string_to_datetime('sometext')

test_datetime_util.py:9: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\..\app\util\datetime_util.py:10: in string_to_datetime
    raise DateTimeFormatException(input_string, 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss')
..\..\app\exception\rtl_exception.py:71: in __init__
    super(DateTimeFormatException, self).__init__()
..\..\app\exception\rtl_exception.py:9: in __init__
    self.response = RtlResponse(self.status_code) \
..\..\app\util\rtl_response_util.py:12: in __init__
    self.rtl_response = {'path': request.path}
C:\Users\RIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py:348: in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
C:\Users\RIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py:307: in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

name = 'request'

    def _lookup_req_object(name):
        top = _request_ctx_stack.top
        if top is None:
>           raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
E           RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
E           
E           This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
E           an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
E           information about how to avoid this problem.

C:\Users\RIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py:38: RuntimeError
```

Which part should be modified to 'test method' normally?

edited) add full log

I think my method raise custom exception, why the test code try to catch the exception in datetime library?

Comment: Is that the full error message/test result? It appears that the `except Exception` block is not catching the raised error. Perhaps you are shadowing the builtin `Exception` name with something else, so that class doesn't match?

Comment: @deceze thanks. I add full log.

Comment: Looks like trying to construct `MyResponse` inside your custom exception is… nonsensical *outside an active request*.

Comment: You are using `MyResponse` that probably needs an active flask context. How to test flask apps is documented [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/testing/) , but you can also try to use [`pytest-flask` plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-flask/)